# Reset custom macOS icon in rEFInd

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, refind

I installed rEFInd the other day to test out some Linux distros.
But what really bugs me is that I have set an icon for my hard drive which is used by rEFInd.

What I tried to reset it:

1. Removing the icon from the hard drive
2. Adding another icon to `/` and named it `.VolumeIcon.png`
3. Reinstalling rEFInd
4. Added another os icons named `boot.png` and `loader.png` to `EFI/refind/icons` on the EFI volume

The only thing that did work was to set another hard drive icon. But I don't want to have an icon at all.

Does anyone know how I could reset rEFInd's cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems to be a caching bug. I finally found a workaround.
To fix it I created an invalid .VolumeIcon.icns on my hard drive, rebooted and removed the icon. Now it works like a charm.

Here are the steps and terminal commands:

**Become Root with sudo su**

```
sudo su
```

**Create invalid .VolumeIcon.icns in root directory of internal hard drive**

```
echo "" > .VolumeIcon.icns
```

**Exit from root user**

```
exit
```

**Reboot your system**

**Remove /.VolumeIcon.icns from root directory of internal hard drive**

```
sudo rm /.VolumeIcon.icns
```